# Scenekit - add red tint to camera

Tags: scenekit, arkit

Is it possible to add a red tint to a given camera in SceneKit? I would like to accomplish this without the (what I consider to be) hacky solution of just trying to shove a red object with < 1 opacity in front of the camera. That could be a solution but I haven't had great success in SceneKit showing an object right in front of the camera.

Also, ideally, I could fade the red tint in and out using SCNAction or some other way.

Finally, a perfect solution would work in ARKit, and give a red tint to the whole world around you. So it would have to be something more than a red scenekit light.

Answer (score 3):

SCNCamera's colorGrading property can do that (that would be the most efficient option).
Using a SCNTechnique to apply a custom post process would work too but it requires an additional pass.
Both options would be faster than a blended node in front of the camera, or a red-ish spritekit overlay or a UIView on top of the SCNView.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Toyos. The SCNTechnique idea seems especially appealing because you have complete control over it. I did a quick google search, and indeed there are working examples of using SCNTechnique to achieve a variety of results (with Scenekit it is rather common that working examples are not to be found). The linked article looked especially useful. Feel free to say no - but any chance you could add a working example of adding a red tint to your answer? If no I will figure it out.

http://blog.simonrodriguez.fr/articles/26-08-2015_a_few_scntechnique_examples.html

Comment: As @toyos noted, though, colorGrading is cheaper to tender than SCNTechnique and probably simpler to implement.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding a red-tinted SCNNode into the scene, you could just add a tinted UIView in front of the ARSCNView in the storyboard. With an outlet to that view fading it in and out would be easy.